# Kinect v2 SDK and javascript based swipe detection

Tags: javascript, kinect-sdk, swipe-gesture

I came across this C# code for swipe detection, but I need a solution that is javascript based. Is anyone aware whether this exists?

https://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Gestures/SwipeGestureDetector.cs

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to catch Gesture because the Kinect will only provide you the raw data in the JavaScript SDK.

Read this thread on Microsoft forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c285b9ae-a8d3-4ed7-bcf6-0b05b03deebf/developing-with-javascript-vs-wpf-c?forum=kinectv2sdk

You will need to make the swipe gesture yourself, maybe this repository on github could help: https://github.com/ekino/ek-winjs-kinect